# Why does the screen goes for 0.1 seconds almost every 2 or 3 seconds in Linux?

Tags: linux

I have problem in ubuntu I use two monitors

1. Laptop monitor
2. External monitor

But there is a problem with the screen of the laptop monitor, almost every 2 or 3 seconds the screen goes out for 0.1 seconds, then it comes, sometimes more, sometimes in a row.

And well, this is only for the screen of the laptop screen that appears. It does not matter if it is the main monitor or not, I even removed that one monitor, but again, this is the same issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: My first guess is connections. This could be external cable, or internal for the laptop screen. I would unplug and re-seat all connectors.

Comment: What does this mean, “…the screen goes for 0.1 seconds…” mean? Goes out? Like it flickers?

Comment: @mitts no . in windows its ok

Comment: You failed to mention that in your initial post. I would suspect an issue with X-server and multiple displays, sounds like a polling issue. If you don't care about the FOSS, then install whatever proprietary graphics drivers are available from your unspecified vendor, or the linux `-non-free` packages.